# programming exercise I found online

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, double, addition

So here is the deal. I found the instructions for this exercise online:

The program below is intended to find the arithmetic mean of the numbers stored in the array q in two ways: once by storing the numbers in an ArrayList d, where you allow all the necessary conversions to be performed automatically; and once by storing them in an ArrayList e, where you perform all the conversions by hand. Complete the program.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 double[] q = { 0.5, 2.4, 7.4, 2.8, -6.2 };
    ArrayList<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> e = new ArrayList<Double>();

    for ( double x : q )
    {
      d.add( x );
      e.add ( new Double ( x ) );
    }

    double dTotal = 0.0,
           eTotal = 0.0; 

//my code goes here
```

I'm not allowed to change the above. What I can change is basically anything below that. I'm thinking it might be simple and it might be super hard. I think I'm supposed to convert data types to an ArrayList but I'm not sure.

EDIT:

Alright, I added in some code:

```
for (double c : d)
{
    double a += c; 
}

for (double f : e)
{
    double b += f;
}

return (a / d.length);
return (b / e.length);
```

I'm getting an error that says "error: ';' expected."

Comment: Write something that solves the requested task, regardless of whether it does "type conversion" or not. Post it over here and then ask about whether your code is or isn't doing type conversion and how to fix it.

Comment: Now you have to find the mean. I don't see the point of having 2 lists though, other than showing that you can box a double into a Double manually.

Comment: @xp500 That *is* the point of the exercise. Calculating the mean is here just to give you some real work to do.

Comment: What does "arithmetic mean" means? Im not familiar with that expression.

Comment: @Xbit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean :(

Comment: @halex

Alright, I switched it to size. I also switched "return" to "System.out.println" in hopes of change. It still gives me The same error.

Answer (score 0):

For `ArrayList` there is no member variable `length` in contrast to the `length` member variable of a plain array. You have to use the instance method [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size%28%29) instead of `length` at the lines where you return.

Another problem is that you can not return 2 values by two return statements the way you are trying. Your second one will raise a compile time error because it's not reachable.

Finally you are summing `c` and `f` to variables that only exist inside the for loop. You have to update the contents of `dTotal` and `eTotal` instead.

I also think that the intention of this exercise is that you should not use any kind of auto(un-)boxing when using `e`.